# Retrieving a numeric value from an html string

Tags: php

I am currently trying to extract a numeric value from an html string. I am currently using `preg_match` but to no luck. All I desire is to get the numeric value set as param of a javascript function `myFunction`. As of now I get an empty array. Any help to achieve this?

```
$data = "<th style='text-align:center;width:33%;'><a onclick='return myfunction(12314568);' href='#test' class='btn mini full'>Test</a> </th>";

preg_match("/\[return myfunction([0-9]+)\]/", $data, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: first off, `(` and `)` have special meaning in regex, so you must escape them. second, where the heck are you getting the `[` and `]` from?  if you remove those, and escape the () , your regex works fine. https://3v4l.org/8qvnH

Comment: @hanshenrik ahh you are absolutely right. Overlooked those two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets need to be removed and the parentheses need to be escaped since they actually appear in the string. You'll then need another set of parentheses to group the numbers so they are separated:

```
preg_match("/return myfunction\(([0-9]+)\)/", $data, $m);
```